# DAPR: target machine actively refused connection (127.0.0.1:3500)

Tags: windows, tcp, .net-6.0, dapr, dapr-sidekick

I read the book
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/dapr-for-net-developers/getting-started and build the sample

"Multi-container Dapr application".

When I run the self-hosted model I receive an error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Dapr.Client.InvocationException: An exception occurred while invoking method: 'weatherforecast' on app-id: 'MyBackEnd'
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:3500)
```

I have restarted my computer but the error appears again. How to fix it?
My OS: Windows 11

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: You mean it " target machine actively refused it" means no listening at 3500?